# How to apply a command to all tabs?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, lua

As title. I want to call a command to all existing tabs to close all windows of specific filetype. How to do so efficiently?

Comment: See :h `:tabdo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially

```
:tabdo windo if &filetype is# 'bad' | close | endif
```

Comment: Oh, I need to learn Vimscript one day! This is much simpler than the one I've written.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] to close all windows of specific filetype.

To achieve this in neovim you can do something like:

```lua
for _, t in ipairs(vim.api.nvim_list_tabpages()) do
  for _, w in ipairs(vim.api.nvim_tabpage_list_wins()) do
    if vim.api.nvim_buf_get_option(vim.api.nvim_win_get_buf(w), 'ft')
      == 'type_you_care' then
      -- do your thing
    end
  end
end
```

since you are me so I know that you want to close all neo-tree windows, so try this instead:

```lua
vim.cmd('tabd Neotree close')
```